# Regarding The Zoom G5n MultiFX processor

Tags: guitar-effects

I am just planning to buy one multiFX processor. I like Zoom G5n. It just sounds great.I have Zoom's G1Xon. It is pretty good. Not that much amazing. But problem is, the volume level is not consistent throughout the patches. Volume fluctuates whenever i go from one patch to another. I was playing some rhythm stuff using clean tones in a church. When the time for a solo came i just changed the patch to some distortion. Suddenly the volume raised to its peak level when i played my first note. Everybody including the band members got shocked. That was the issue. Now also this pedal has the same issue. Now am using Vox Stomplab 2g. I don't have any volume issues with Vox. I just want to buy Zoom G5n. I've seen some reviews on YouTube. It just sounds amazing. But am afraid of the volume fluctuation issue. Is there anybody using this pedal? Can someone guide me.. Also I want to know about its built quality. Is it made of plastic or metal? Is it hard enough to carry on the road ??
Thank you so much...
Wesli

Answer (score 1):

The volume issue is surely fixable via editing the patches. You might have to save it to a "user" patch first—some pedals have a number of built-in presets that *aren't* editable but you can instead copy/save it to a different patch that *is* editable. Anyway, there's probably a master volume setting for each patch and if not you'd just need to adjust whatever amp model or effect is causing it to be so loud.

I can't tell definitively from the pictures whether it's metal or plastic because of the matte black color, but it looks like the housing might be metal and some of the foot switches are plastic. In either case, Zoom has never really been known for great build quality. That said, if you take care of it and keep it protected while in transit, it should be fine.

Comment: i have the zoom B2.1 and its so strong that its almost bomb proof so I'm not sure that's totally true.

Answer (score 0):

Hard enough to carry on the road? That issue is easily solved by getting a decent briefcase, fitting it with some foam, and always using it to transport. There's room in a case for the pedalboard, leads and mains adaptor, and it looks professional too. Second-hand briefcase -

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine bought a Zoom G5n recently and I've spent an afternoon with him playing with it.

What I can say is that it is very versatile and the amp simulations are nice sounding. The patch volume issue can be easily addressed setting the master volume of each patch. The casing is mostly plastic, but looks solid enough.

Since my friend is very happy with his new acquisition, I'd guess he'd recommend it.